# jquery get element where the cursor is

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm building a splittesting tool for my website with javascript and jquery. Now I want to show  for each elements I want to splittest a little hovermenu when the cursor passes over the element in my previewbox. Is there any possibility to do something like this ? I treid something like this

```
$('body').hover(function(event){
    console.log(event.target.nodeName);
    // to see if it's showing up the element   
});
```

but it's only triggering once. As I don't want to use click since I want also to showup the menu on anchor elements I'm a bit lost

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe you want to use the `mousemove` event here instead of the `hover` event.

```
$('body').mousemove(function(evt){
    console.log(evt.target);
});
```

Just remember to use `mousemove` with extreme caution.

[See an example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/zs45B/)

Answer (score 15):

If you are using the keyboard and not the mouse:
Not jQuery, just plain JavaScript for those who are interested:

```
getSelection().getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer.parentNode
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use `document.elementFromPoint` for this.

```
var element = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
```

For ex:

```
$('body').hover(function(event){
    var el = document.elementFromPoint(event.pageX, event.pageY);
});
```

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.elementFromPoint

Comment: This will keep triggering once also. And, why would anyone want to use `document.elementFromPoint` when you can get the element for free from `event`?

Comment: @Alexander - In this particular case, yes. But to the OP's original question of "jquery get element where the cursor is" - `document.elementFromPoint` is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways to do so:

1. Something like that:

   ```
   $('body').on('mousemove', function() {
    console.log($(':hover').last().attr('name'));
   });
   ```
2. For debugging purpose you can jush type in chrome console `$(':hover').last()`
   Than hover mouse where you want and press Enter to run this console command.
3. If you want to use it constatly, I recommend not to use mousemove event. Use something like that

   ```
   $('.one_of_your_trigger_element').on('mouseenter', function() {
    var hover_element = $(':hover').last();
    ...
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below coding it will help you...

```
    <body onMouseMove="javaScript:mouseEventHandler(event);">

    <script>
    function mouseEventHandler(mEvent) {
// Internet Explorer
                alert(mEvent.srcElement.nodeName); //Display Node Name
                alert(mEvent.srcElement.id); //Display Element ID
//FireFox
                alert(mEvent.target.nodeName);//Display Node Name
                alert(mEvent.target.id);//Display Element ID
            }
    </script>
```