# get ID of element under cursor in shiny

Tags: shiny, shinyjs

In my Shiny app, the user mouses over some HTML output which consists of several spans, like this:

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <span id="span1">foo</span>
    <span id="span2">bar</span>
</div>
```

I want to get the ID of the span which the user is currently mousing over as a shiny input$... 
I know there are lots of js ways to do it, [jquery get element where the cursor is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464293/jquery-get-element-where-the-cursor-is), but I don't know how to integrate with Shiny, e.g. by using shinyjs https://deanattali.com/shinyjs/extend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this, if I correctly understand:

```
library(shiny)

js <- "
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('span').on('mouseover', function(evt){
    Shiny.setInputValue('span', evt.target.id);
  });
})
"

ui <- basicPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(HTML(js))),
  tags$div(
    tags$span(id = "span1", "foo"),
    tags$span(id = "span2", "bar")
  ),
  br(),
  verbatimTextOutput("span")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output[["span"]] <- renderPrint({
    input[["span"]]
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: that's exactly what I meant.

Comment: ... but it turns out it still doesn't help me because I didn't fully describe the problem :-( because my spans are dynamically generated as uiOutput not as ordinary shiny tags. Indeed the source html of the page doesn't show them either. So I don't know what to do.

Comment: @StevePowell You should open a new question with an app which produces this problem.