# how to get the id of a span in dynamic output in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I can get the id of a span element in Shiny using js thanks to [Stephane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58541195/get-id-of-element-under-cursor-in-shiny/58549593?noredirect=1#comment103446343_58549593) but not if the element is produced dynamically (indeed the contents of the dynamic elements are not contained in the source code of the HTML page produced). Any ideas how I can access the ids also of dynamic elements?

```
library(shiny)

js <- "
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('span').on('mouseover', function(evt){
    Shiny.setInputValue('span', evt.target.id);
  });
})
"

ui <- basicPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(HTML(js))),
  tags$div(
    tags$span(id = "span1", "foo"),
    tags$span(id = "span2", "bar")
  ),                                   # mousing over these spans triggers the output in the verbatimTextOutput
  br(),
  uiOutput("dynamicArea"),             # mousing over these spans does NOT trigger the output in the verbatimTextOutput
  br(),
  verbatimTextOutput("span")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output[["span"]] <- renderPrint({
    input[["span"]]
  })

output[["dynamicArea"]] <- renderUI({
  tags$div(
    tags$span(id = "spandynamic1", "foo2"),
    tags$span(id = "spandynamic2", "bar2") 
  ) 
})
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this JS code:

```
js <- "
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').on('mouseover', 'span', function(evt){
    Shiny.setInputValue('span', evt.target.id);
  });
})
"
```

Comment: I know we aren't supposed to say "thanks that's amazing", but thanks, that is amazing! Didn't know it was possible.